# What concrete datatype is created when I use the Seq[T] constructor?

Tags: scala, collections, traits, seq

Scala allows me to instantiate an object that implements the `Seq` trait directly using this syntax:

```
val numbers: Seq[Int] = Seq(1, 2, 3)
val names: Seq[String] = Seq("Alice", "Bob", "Charles")
```

1. Since `Seq` is a trait and not a concrete implementation, what data type underlies `numbers` and `names`?
2. What's the best way I could have figured this out for myself?
3. Is it idiomatic to create a trait object directly?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`List` is the default implementation. You can easily test this in the Scala REPL:

```
scala> val numbers: Seq[Int] = Seq(1, 2, 3)
numbers: Seq[Int] = List(1, 2, 3)

scala> val names: Seq[String] = Seq("Alice", "Bob", "Charles")
names: Seq[String] = List(Alice, Bob, Charles)
```

As far as what is better (creating `List` or `Seq`), I think it's about preference. Both options are available, and as far as I know the compiler does not complain when choosing one over the other. I personally always use `Seq`.

Comment: Note that there are significant pros and cons of using `List` over other `Seq` implementations (e.g. lists are faster to update, `Vector` is faster to index into). I'll usually use the more specific type to make this obvious when it matters, otherwise `Seq` is simpler.

Answer (score 5):

For completeness: the answer can also be found in `Seq`'s (the *object*, not the *trait*) [Scaladocs](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.4/index.html#scala.collection.Seq$):

> This object provides a set of operations to create Seq values. The current default implementation of a Seq is a List.